# Is it possible to replace notify-osd with Gnome 3 Indicators?

Tags: 11.04, gnome, notify-osd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome 3 notifications are replaced with notify-osd when the machine goes to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72646/gnome-3-notifications-are-replaced-with-notify-osd-when-the-machine-goes-to-slee)

I have gnome shell installed in ubuntu 11.04 fully. It still, however, uses the ubuntu notification rounded transparent rectangle notifiers at the top right of the screen.

What I want is for it to use the default gnome shell indicators, those that use the tray and hot corner at the bottom right of the screen.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: IMHO this is not a duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/72646/gnome-3-notifications-are-replaced-with-notify-osd-when-the-machine-goes-to-slee . A more recent, similar question is http://askubuntu.com/questions/101606/gnome-style-notifications-in-unity/239928#239928

Answer (score 2):

You should just use GNOME Shell in 11.10, it will work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to wait for 11.10 to come out and if you dont whanna wait then u can try the beta. Unless you whant to make the work rysking data,but still to make it easy and if i were you i would just wait for the 11.10 oneiric oncelot to come out because they have GNOME 3 available along side unity and what your triyng to do is higly risky and nearly impossibly {note:i said nearly}

Answer (score 0):

I'm reasonably certain that those will only run if you have gnome3 fully installed. Unity does not run on Gnome3 at the moment, so you will probably have to run them through Gnome-Shell (which is quite nice by the way)

Edit: See comment by Uri Herrera below for more detail.

Comment: hmm... so i couldn't, say, purge the unity notifications and use the gnome notification daemon or something?

Comment: no, put simply these are for gnome 2.32 , built with gtk2 , those that you want are for gnome 3.0 built with gtk 3 , you may be able to use gnome 2 indicators on gnome 3 (if possible) but not the other way around.

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address the question (not trying to be biased against GNOME Shell, but I think what he is trying to ask is if he can use certain Shell features within Unity - which you cannot in this case).

Answer (score -1):

Try to uninstall notify-osd package and restart.

Comment: That will only break the system. Too risky