# Gnome 3 notifications are replaced with notify-osd when the machine goes to sleep

Tags: 11.10, gnome, notify-osd

A similar question [exists for 11.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47724/is-it-possible-to-replace-notify-osd-with-gnome-3-indicators), but the answers were "wait for 11.10; it'll work there." 11.10 has arrived, and it dun broke on me. :-(

When I first started using Gnome Shell, the Gnome 3 notifications worked fine. After suspending and resuming, it appears to have reverted to the Unity notify-osd bubbles. This is annoying, because a bunch of notify-osd bubbles become little windows in the middle of the screen when the computer suspends. They also become queued up in the Gnome Shell notification bar at the bottom of the screen, all with the label "notify-osd".

[image: Behold the windows!]

If I log out and back in, notify-osd is gone and the Gnome 3 indicators are back until I put the machine to sleep. But how can I keep them permanently?

Answer (score 3):

notifications are sent via DBUS and after installing notify-osd it redirects all notifications to itself.

This would not be particulary troublesome if not so many packages would depend on notify-osd directly (ubuntu-desktop, blueman, guake, update-notifier, network-manager-gnome, rhythmbox to name a few), efffectively breaking the ability to choose the notification system I'd like.

You can remove the diversion with the following command:

```
sudo dpkg-divert --remove --rename --package notify-osd --divert /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service.notify-osd /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

But (I haven't tested this) this might either break updates of notify-osd (and thus your system) in a bad way or it might just reappear on the next update of notify-osd.

Answer (score 0):

This question (Oct. 2011) does not ask for the same information as this earlier one:
[Is it possible to replace notify-osd with Gnome 3 Indicators?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47724/is-it-possible-to-replace-notify-osd-with-gnome-3-indicators?lq=1) (June 2011). This other question (June 2011) is more comprehensive than merely asking for a fix but rather asks how to control the environment, which may or may not also apply to this problem (Oct. 2011).

Consequently, the following AU information is likely relevant to only the earlier (June 2011) question:
[Use notify-osd instead notification-daemon in GNOME-Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350488/use-notify-osd-instead-notification-daemon-in-gnome-shell?lq=1)

This provides information on how to create the situation that needs remedial attention for the original posted question above. It is not likely that this was how the above problem manifested so undoing and reversing the steps probably will not give resolution. However, it is relevant to the June 2011 post and directly addresses the issues requested there.

The system file (pangolin 12.04):

```
file:///usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

contents are:

```
    [D-BUS Service]
    Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
    Exec=/bin/sh -c 'if
         [ ! -x /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = guest-restricted ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = gnome-classic-guest-restricted ]
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = default -a
              "$(basename `readlink /etc/alternatives/x-session-manager`)" =
                    gnome-session ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = ubuntu ] ||
         [ "$GDMSESSION" = ubuntu-2d ];
      then exec /usr/lib/notify-osd/notify-osd;
      else exec /usr/lib/notification-daemon/notification-daemon; fi'
```

presumably, switching the code segments that are **`bold`** will do the switch, but whether the change is actually functional is another matter. (ie. Do both `notification-daemon` **&** `notify-osd` exist? etc.)

ref:

- [Is it possible to replace notify-osd with Gnome 3 Indicators?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/47724/is-it-possible-to-replace-notify-osd-with-gnome-3-indicators?lq=1)
- [Use notify-osd instead notification-daemon in GNOME-Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/350488/use-notify-osd-instead-notification-daemon-in-gnome-shell?lq=1)
- [Clickable Gnome-style notifications in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101606/gnome-style-notifications-in-unity?lq=1)
- [How to disable Unity style notification when using Gnome Shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132033/how-to-disable-unity-style-notification-when-using-gnome-shell?lq=1)
- [Gnome 3 notifications are replaced with notify-osd when the machine goes to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72646/gnome-3-notifications-are-replaced-with-notify-osd-when-the-machine-goes-to-slee?lq=1)
- [How to install NotifyOSD-Config?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72215/how-to-install-notifyosd-config?lq=1)
- [Gnome 3 notifications are replaced with notify-osd when the machine goes to sleep](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72646/gnome-3-notifications-are-replaced-with-notify-osd-when-the-machine-goes-to-slee?lq=1)