# Clickable Gnome-style notifications in Unity

Tags: unity, gnome

I was looking for a way to get gnome style notifications in Unity. Or at least, if there´s a way of making the default Unity notifications interactive and clickable? As it is by default only a notification pops up and the user needs to find the relevant window, which I find very counterproductive.

Comment: This is very nearly a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/47724/is-it-possible-to-replace-notify-osd-with-gnome-3-indicators). Also [this one](http://askubuntu.com/questions/72215/how-to-install-notifyosd-config) which points to [this Webupd8](http://www.webupd8.org/2011/05/configurable-notifyosd-bubbles-for.html) post. Have you tried any of these? If you did, what didn't work?

Comment: "this one" mentioned relates to changing display duration, not making them "interactive and clickable". The Webupd8 solution requires adding a PPA, while a simpler solution exists, see [below](http://askubuntu.com/questions/101606/gnome-style-notifications-in-unity/239928#239928)

Comment: Do not take the accepted answer as the only solution; as @StéphaneGourichon points out, a much better solution is below and it works swimmingly in Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible.

Ubuntu's notification system, [NotifyOSD](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NotifyOSD#bubble), as used by Unity, is designed to be un-clickable, in order to simplify the experience and not confuse users. There is no way to change that.

Gnome Shell, on the other hand, uses another built-in notification system that behaves differently to NotifyOSD, as explained in this [LXNews article](https://web.archive.org/web/20120126025211/http://lxnews.org/2011/01/08/gnome-shell-notifications-explained/)

Comment: Link to "gnome-shell-notifications-explained" is broken. I was really interested to follow it. Can we fix it? Thanks!

Comment: I'm sorry, I couldn't find the article online anymore

Comment: It's mirrored on Internet Archive

Comment: Actually, this isn't entirely true. The **NotifyOSD Configuration** application allows you to make Unity notifications clickable.  See [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/128508/518089) for more info. Works in 14.04 for me.

Answer (score 40):

## You can have clickable notification with Unity.

Tested with 12.10, 13.04, 13.10, 14.04, 14.10, 16.04 (thanks @ManseUK).

### What we want

Notification are supposed to non-obstrusive, non-disrupting of your train of thought, and provide a shortcut when relevant.

### Problem in Unity ([12.04](/questions/tagged/12.04), [12.10](/questions/tagged/12.10) at least)

Default notification engine is notify-osd.

- notifications are not clickable (which hurts efficiency for those that offer to quickly bring you to the place of interest).
- when several happen quickly, they queue and appear only one after the other : no way to see them quickly, you just have to ... wait.

### Solution

Current **XFCE notifications** on the other hand implement just that, and they **can be used with Unity**. I just tested it with a separate account (default config) to rule out any user-specific settings.

### Howto

Here's how install and use XFCE4's notifications instead of Unity's:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-notifyd ; sudo apt-get purge notify-osd
```

To get immediate effect this may help (else logout/login):

```
killall -v notify-osd
/usr/lib/*/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd &
```

You might want to test and adjust appearance:

```
xfce4-notifyd-config
```

Comment: +1 This looks interesting. I'm afraid to try it just now as I'm on 12.04 and in the middle of another project. Thanks for posting it though! I'd really like to switch to this soon.

Comment: @tom-brossman Thanks for your feedback. I changed the order of the apt-get : first install new daemon, then remove other, to ensure dependencies are met at all times.

Comment: @StéphaneGourichon is there any way, that when you click on notification, it would open/focus that program where notification came from?

Comment: @Ville Rouhiainen From what I understand, it's the sending application's job to ask for a specific "action" doing this (and hope the notifyd supports it, which is not always). It may be possible to modify `xfce4-notifyd` (or other implementations) to offer such an action for all applications. Reference https://people.gnome.org/~mccann/docs/notification-spec/notification-spec-latest.html . Suggestion : open a wish on https://bugzilla.xfce.org/buglist.cgi?product=Xfce4-notifyd

Comment: +1 Working on 16.04 too - if Evolution Mail changed the sending font my life would be completed lol Thanks

Comment: This works but breaks Unity Tweak Tool. It says: "com.cannonical.notify-osd is missing. In order to work properly, Unity Tweak Tool recommends you to install the necessary packages."

Answer (score 0):

#### Tested on Ubuntu Unity 18.04

You do not need to purge or remove notify-osd to switch to xfce4-notifyd. You can simply change the default notification utility.

**Before you begin**, install `xfce4-notifyd` by running the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install xfce4-notifyd
```

**Next**, run the following command to edit your default, dbus notification-service configuration file:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/dbus-1/services/org.freedesktop.Notifications.service
```

**Then**, edit the file to look like this:

```
[D-BUS Service]
Name=org.freedesktop.Notifications
# Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/notify-osd
Exec=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xfce4/notifyd/xfce4-notifyd
SystemdService=xfce4-notifyd.service
```

<sub>**If you notice, the 3rd line is commented out and the last two lines are added to the original file.**</sub>

When you are done editing, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>o</kbd> to save the file and then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> to exit nano.

**Finally**, reboot to apply the changes.