# How can I make clicking Notify-OSD notifications bring me to their application/message?

Tags: configuration, notify-osd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Gnome-style notifications in Unity](https://askubuntu.com/questions/101606/gnome-style-notifications-in-unity)

I would like to be able to click on a notification so that the App opens and shows the message. Say I get a Pidgin message, a click on the notification should open the Pidgin message window and show the message so that i can quickly answer. The same goes for email notifications and thunderbird and so on.

Either the entire notification field should be clickable or there should be a button.

Is there any way I can get this feature?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, Notify OSD is crippled *by design*. It's there to display a message for a period of time and then vanish. That's all.

However there are alternatives. You can install `notification-daemon` and after a log-out-then-in you should be seeing bubbles you can interact with. They're themed in a similar way and notifications you miss will be sent to a tray (Notification Area/Indicator Applet) icon.

If you don't like it, just remove that package and do the log-out-in conga again. Notify OSD should take the helm again.

Comment: Really? Crippled by design?

Comment: @Oli I have notification-daemon installed, but notify-osd rules.. :( any help?

Comment: thanks! this is helpful! why won't they make notify-osd clickable or closeable. this would be the most logical way to deal with a notification.

Comment: It is logical to limit the number of times the computer is able to tell you what to do. It's disruptive. The clear distinction between indicators and notifications, allows you to stay up to date without so much interruption. When there is something you should probably react to, there's an indication to remind you of it, but without requiring you to do so in order for the bubble to go away, and without requiring you to do so while the bubble is open. You are the human. The computer is not your equal. Certainly not your boss.

Comment: @Jo-ErlendSchinstad There is a difference between "requiring" and "allowing". Having to click all notifications would be annoying, but I also find annoying having to wait for a notification to close, for me to be able to click something that's behind it.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Notify-OSD can't be used to open the application for which the notification is all about. So to answer your question, Notify-OSD is not clickable. Like its name connotes it only NOTIFIES users. Hope this helps.